# WCF Client calling method with polymorphic array fails

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, polymorphism

I have a WCF service with the following (example) interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Foo))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Bar))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Baz))]
public interface IMyInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    void ProcessMessage(Message message);

    [OperationContract]
    void ProcessMessages(IEnumerable<Message> messages);
}
```

`Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` are all a type of `Message`.

I can call `ProcessMessage()` from a WCF client with either a `Foo`, `Bar` or `Baz` object and everything works fine. I can't, however, call `ProcessMessages(...)` with an array (or list or any other `IEnumerable`) because this will fail:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:messages. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'X.X.Foo' with data contract name
>   'Foo:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/X.X' is not expected.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known
>   statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException
>   for more details.

When I take a look at the generated client code, `reference.cs`, I see:

```
...
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyInterface/ProcessMessage", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyInterface/ProcessMessageResponse")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(X.X.Foo))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(X.X.Bar))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(X.X.Baz))]
void ProcessMessage(X.X.Message message);

...
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyInterface/ProcessMessages", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IMyInterface/ProcessMessagesResponse")]
void ProcessMessages(X.X.Message[] messages);
```

I notice the `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute`s are added to `ProcessMessage` but not `ProcessMessages`. When I manually add the same set of `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute`s to the `ProcessMessages` method and I call it from the client with an array containing a `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` it works fine.

How do I get Visual Studio to generate these attributes on the second method too? Is my `IMyInterface` wrong? Did I add the `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(...))]` in the wrong place? Where did I go wrong?

**Edit**
I should, maybe, mention that the `Message` class is in an "external" assembly (which I can control, luckily) which I packaged in a Nuget package which, in turn, is referenced in both the WCF service and client with the "reuse types..." option enabled for this assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your types are in different assemblies, and/or it's hard to modify `Message`, you can put this in the client assembly to make it work:

```
namespace X.X
{
    [KnownType(typeof(Foo))]
    public partial class Foo
    {
    }
    [KnownType(typeof(Bar))]
    public partial class Bar
    {
    }
    [KnownType(typeof(Baz))]
    public partial class Baz
    {
    }
}
```

(I know it seems like you're telling it the bleedingly obvious, but it works.)

If `Message`, `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` were in the same assembly, you could just add the [`KnownType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute to your `Message` class:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Foo))]
[KnownType(typeof(Bar))]
[KnownType(typeof(Baz))]
public abstract class Message
```

Then you wouldn't have to do anything special to your clients.

Also, the only way I was able to reproduce your behavior was by putting `Message` in its own assembly, referencing that from both my client and WCF library projects, and using the "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" checkbox. If the classes are all generated on the client side, instead of some being referenced and some generated, it works much more simply, because it generates all the `KnownType` attributes on `Message`.

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow; however that will take some effort since `Message` is in another project, stuffed in a Nuget package etc. so I'll have some re-compiling and re-building to do...

Comment: @RobIII I've updated my answer. It should be a better solution for you.

Comment: I like the partial class solution, but won't the "original" classes need to be partial already for that to work? I'm glad you could reproduce the problem; I will update my question to include the fact that the `Message` class is in an external assembly; that might be relevant indeed. I did, indeed, reuse types for obvious reasons. **edit** Also: are you sure your answer on the partial class part is correct since `Foo` has a `[KnownType(typeof(Foo))]` attribute? Shouldn't that be `[KnownType(typeof(Message))]` or something or even the other way around; add the attributes on the `Message` class?

Comment: @RobIII Generated classes are marked `partial`, so you can do things like this. I was assuming `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` were part of Reference.cs. Are they (from the client's perspective) in Reference.cs, `Message`'s assembly, or a different external assembly? And yes, `Foo` has a `KnownType` of `Foo`. That's why I pointed out that it looks you're telling it the bleedingly obvious. =)

Comment: `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` are in the external assembly, as is `Message`.

Comment: I added the `KnownType` attributes to Message in the shared assembly and removed the attributes from the IMyInterface and this solved my problem. Thanks!